# How to fix - code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I made a `npm update` early today and everything worked fine but now when I try to start the server I get the error below?

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: try running ```npm i``` again

Comment: Hi @Mintee, if you are satisfied then please accept an answer so that question is closed.

Comment: @SumitSingh It worked, but I could only accept the answer after 7 min and then I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `npm install` again.